# Login from device without browser

Tags: facebook, authentication

I'm developing software that run on a device without the ability to show a browser to the user. I'm in a situation like [this](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/2760676/facebook-open-graph-without-a-browser). I would integrate this software with Facebook. 
I could get username and password from the user, pass this infos to my server and use something like screen scraper to get the HTML from Facebook and fill the authentication form.

Is there a good way? Is there any official way to do something like this?

I've seen a similar behavior on many games in PSVita for example ...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with Java, you can try using this library: http://facebook4j.org/en/index.html

The biggest issue we faced was authentication, but once you're in it should be pretty easy to work with.